# Lambda function behavior

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to understand the behavior of the lambda below. What value is actually passing on to argument `pair`? This will help me understand the return part `pair[1]`.

```
pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])
print (pairs)
```

As I understand, `sort` will sort the list `pairs`. It will compare if a function is passed as a parameter. So how I'm I getting the below output:

```
OUTPUT:
[(4, 'four'), (1, 'one'), (3, 'three'), (2, 'two')]
```

Comment: The lambda gets the second item of the tuple. That's why the resulting list is sorted alphabetically by the second item.

Comment: I believe the `pair` argument is taking in the individual tuples in my list, in which case the sort makes sense. Please let me know if I understand correctly ?

Comment: @kindall Thanks, I believe you already clarified even before I completed typing. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort by the numeric value, change your lambda to

```
pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[0])
```

Python is zero-indexed. The first element of each tuple has index 0. `pair[1]` would refer to the words in the tuple, not the numbers. So if you want to sort by the text, alphabetically, what you have works.

If you want to see what's being passed through the lambda --- which was your question:

```
from __future__ import print_function #Needed if you're on Python 2
pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: print(pair[1]))
```

Which returns

```
one
two
three
four
```

Verify this by checking the output if you `print(pair[0])` or `print(pair)`.

Answer (score 2):

The lambda function receives a parameter which in your case is a tuple of size 2 and returns the second element (the number in word format in your case). the sort method will sort your pairs list according to the key you pass to it, which is the lambda function in your code. In python, when sorting a list of strings, it will sort in lexicographically, so your code will sort the pairs in a way that the 2nd elements are sorted lexicographically.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid `lambda` expressions where possible. At one point, they were going to be eliminated from the language altogether, and various helper functions and classes were introduced to fill the void that would be left behind. (Ultimately, `lambda` expressions survived, but the helpers remained.)

One of those was the `itemgetter` class, which can be used to define functions suitable for use with `sort`.

```
from operator import itemgetter
pairs.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
```

(As @metropolis points out, you want to use 0, not 1, to sort by the initial integer component of each pair.)